# Changing NavigationView background to round shape not working when pressed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-navigationview, material-components, material-components-android

I am setting navigation item background using `app:itemBackground` in layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/nav_selector_background"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>
```

Here is `nav_selector_background.xml`

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:color="@color/colorNavItemSelected">
<item android:id="@android:id/mask">
    <color android:color="#000"/> <!-- any color will do -->
</item>

<item
        android:right="8dp">
    <selector>
        <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/nav_item_background_round"/>
        <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/nav_item_background_round"/>
        <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/nav_item_background_round"/>
        <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@drawable/nav_item_background_round"/>
        <item android:state_active="true" android:drawable="@drawable/nav_item_background_round" />
        <item android:state_hovered="true" android:drawable="@drawable/nav_item_background_round" />
        <item android:state_drag_hovered="true" android:drawable="@drawable/nav_item_background_round" />
        <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
    </selector>

</item>
```

And `nav_item_background_round`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/colorNavItemSelected"/>
            <corners android:bottomRightRadius="32dp"
                     android:topRightRadius="32dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Problem is when I press on the item the whole background is highlighted as seen in the screenshot. I only want the red part highlighted.

[image]

I uploaded the sample on [Github](https://github.com/tadeas-braun/SampleAppTwo) if anybody is interested in compiling and running the app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the [`NavigationView`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/NavigationView.md) in the [MaterialComponents libarry](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) you can use:

- **`app:itemShapeAppearanceOverlay`** attribute to define a custom shape for the each item
- **`app:itemShapeFillColor`** attribute to define the color used to fill the shape

Something like:

```
  <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
      app:itemShapeFillColor="@color/selector_menu"
      app:itemShapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.Nav"
      android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.NavigationView"
      ../>
```

where the selector is something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:alpha="0.50" android:color="@color/primaryColor" android:state_pressed="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.12" android:color="@color/primaryColor" android:state_activated="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.12" android:color="@color/primaryColor" android:state_checked="true"/>
  <item android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
</selector>
```

and the shape is defined by:

```
  <style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.Nav" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeTopRight">50%</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomRight">50%</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomLeft">0dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeTopLeft">0dp</item>
  </style>
```

Also use the `android:theme` to override the color used by the ripple.

```
  <style name="ThemeOverlay.NavigationView" parent="">
    <item name="android:colorControlHighlight">@android:color/transparent</item>
  </style>
```

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to use `app:itemShapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.Nav"` but ggeting below error `style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.Nav) not found` I'm using `material:1.1.0-beta01` any idea

Comment: @NileshRathod sorry my bad. I've just updated the answer.

Comment: great solution. but there is no white space in the right of nav item.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want but I think this will solve your problem.

nav_item_background_round.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:color="#f816a463"
        tools:targetApi="lollipop">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#f816a463" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. What I want is to have round end on one side but as seen in the picture when pressed the highlighted background overlaps the round end. I want the same effect as in Google Keep app for Android.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue. I resolved it by

First - Adding a custom style to my navigationView *app:theme="@style/NavigationDrawerStyle"*

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fadingEdge="none"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    app:itemIconPadding="12dp"
    app:itemBackground="@drawable/drawer_background_selector"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/drawer_item_icon_color"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/drawer_item_text_color"
    app:theme="@style/NavigationDrawerStyle"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" >
```

Second - Then in my styles.xml created a custom drawer style *NavigationDrawerStyle* then
 setting *colorControlHighlight* to transparent which removed the rectangular shape for me.

```
<style name="NavigationDrawerStyle" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.navTheme">
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/robotomedium</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlHighlight">@android:color/transparent</item><!--Here Removes Rectangle-->
</style>
```