# How to change navigationdrawer shape in Android

Tags: android, shapes

I need to know how i can change navigationdrawer shape.
[image]

I am using com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView

Comment: Follow this. It might be in help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53574593/changing-navigationview-background-to-round-shape-not-working-when-pressed

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:background` attribute in your navigation view to set your custom drawable as the background of your navigationView (drawer).

Comment: I dont have a clue how to make image not clickable if the image is not in the clicking area. Eg have alpha channel.